# Intermediate image

Tags: swing, bufferedimage

I have a problem with intermediate image.  The image is showing only once.  After i move the image "line" is not showing anymore.

```
public void paintLine(Graphics g) {
    if (line == null) {
        line = new BufferedImage(1, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics gImg = line.getGraphics();
        float[] data = datas[index];
        for (float f : data) {
            float[] rgb = ColorMap.getPixelColor(f);
            gImg.setColor(new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
            gImg.drawRect(0, (int)yPos--, 1, 1);
        }
        gImg.dispose();
    }
    xIncr++;
    g.drawImage(line, (int)xPos - xIncr, (int)yPos, null);
    graph.repaint();
}
```

This method is called in paintComponent ofJPanel.
If i recreate the image "line" each time, it is displaying properly with really poor performance.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: can't say anything to the problem you stated - but the code as-is is problematic: looks like you call repaint in the paint cycle, thus producing a loop which is non-fatal only accidentally ...

Comment: Yes for the call to repaint, i removed it from the method, and i fixed the problem of my intermediate image.  The problem was in the for loop, the yPos of drawRect method.  It is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... I am not pretty sure owing to less information in your question but, as a rule, image may disappear because of doubleBuffered(false) option. So you need to set the double buffered option to true manually for your canvas. Code something like this

```
public class MyLabel extends JLabel{


public MyLabel()
{

this.setDoubleBuffered(true);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  this.paintLine(g);
}

public void paintLine(Graphics g) {
    if (line == null) {
        line = new BufferedImage(1, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics gImg = line.getGraphics();
        float[] data = datas[index];
        for (float f : data) {
            float[] rgb = ColorMap.getPixelColor(f);
            gImg.setColor(new Color(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
            gImg.drawRect(0, (int)yPos--, 1, 1);
        }
        //gImg.dispose();
    }
    xIncr++;
    g.drawImage(line, (int)xPos - xIncr, (int)yPos, null);
    graph.repaint();
}
}
```

Now I guess the conception is more clear

Good luck